# Programmatically generate list of plugin dependencies without gradleApi and localGroovy

Tags: groovy, gradle, classpath

#### Background

I would like to make regression tests of [my plugin](https://github.com/szpak/gradle-pitest-plugin) with [nebula-test](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-test). My plugin is written in Groovy, but it is simple and when built with Gradle 1.x can be used in project with Gradle 2.x. Currently I am able to test it automatically with Gradle 1.x only due to Gradle and Groovy [conflicts on classpath](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-test/issues/13) (when running from Gradle 2.x there are both Gradle 1.x and 2.x and Groovy 1.8.6 and 2.3.6 dependencies). As a workaround I would like put on the classpath only runtime dependencies of my plugin (excluding JARs provided by `gradleApi` and `localGroovy`) and I need to generate that list when running a Gradle build script for my plugin (when tests are running it is too late to determine what included given JAR).

#### Question

How can I programmatically (e.g. task in build.gradle) generate the list of runtime dependencies (in fact JARs added to the classpath by them + build/class/main and build/resources/main) **without** those which come from `gradleApi` and `localGroovy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
configurations {
    gradleDeps
}

dependencies {
    gradleDeps gradleApi() // includes localGroovy
    compile configurations.gradleDeps
    compile ...
    runtime ...
}

def runtimeWithoutGradleDeps = configurations.runtime - configurations.gradleDeps

task printFiles {
    doLast {
        runtimeWithoutGradleDeps.each { println it }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I've got an error: `Could not find method gradle() for arguments [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency_Decorated@433edba9] on root project ...` on the line with `gradle gradleApi()` with both Gradle 1.12 and 2.1. I had to use `configurations.create("gradle")` and `compile configurations.gradle` to make it work. Btw, why `sourceSets.main.output` is **not** in the `configurations.runtime`? Is there some easier way than adding them manually to the list with files?

Comment: Fixed the naming problem. Configurations are typically about external dependencies. In a typical build, `sourceSets.main.output` will be part of `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath`, but not part of `configurations.runtime`.

Comment: Ok. I ended up with `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath - configurations.gradle` to get my classes/resources and dependent JARs. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't need adding additional configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.ant:ant-javamail:1.9.0'
    compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4'
    compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}

task deps << {
    def home = project.gradle.startParameter.gradleHomeDir
    project.configurations.runtime.files.findAll { f ->
        !f.absolutePath.startsWith(home.absolutePath)
    }.each {
        println it
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea with `project.gradle.startParameter.gradleHomeDir`. Unfortunately it is quite fragile. On my system it failed because I use symlinks and dependencies were resolved with the real path, why the home with the path using a symlink. Btw, it also fails to take into consideration `build/class/main` and `build/resources/main`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Nevertheless will leave the response. Maybe anyone will find it useful.